# Какая то глупая ошибка

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Мне выдает такую ошибку:

> java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Ошибка ввода/вывода: Invalid connection string format, a valid format is: "//host[:port][/service_name]"

Не смотря на то что мой код выглядит корректно:

```
public final DataBaseModel dbm;
public AddFrame(final RegisterFrame frame){
        user = frame.getUser();
        passwd = frame.getPasswd();
        host = frame.getHost();
        port = frame.getPort();
        serviceName = frame.getServiceName();
        dbm = new DataBaseModel("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//" + host + ":" + port + "/" + serviceName, "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", user, passwd);
```

С чем может быть связана эта проблема?

Comment: что-то одно выберите, или `@hostName` или `://127.0.0.1:12345`.. помоему так.

Comment: У меня есть одно окно, которое отображает данные из бд в таблице и кнопка, после нажатия которой открывается второе окно для добавления данных, так вот в первом случае все срабатывает, а в этом вот такую вот ошибку выдает. Так что я даже и понять не могу что с этим делать

Comment: попробуйте стереть собачку  :)

Comment: по пробовал вывести мои данные которые поступают для подключения и что оказалось, он не поступают вообще, буду думать как это исправить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена

Нашёл ошибку. Дело в том, что сначала у меня выводится окно для ввода логина пользователя, пароля, хоста, порта и имени сервис. После нажатия на кнопку осуществляется вход: открывается окно с таблицами подключенной БД и кнопкой для нового окна с полями для ввода строки, которую хочу добавить.

Оказалось: в первом окне после нажатия кнопки "вход" данные поступают для соединения с БД, открывают новое окно и стираются, то есть `userField.setText(null)` и тд. Так что это просто моя не внимательность.